# Observable <Interface[]> showing properties as undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Im getting items from a cart service and putting them into my shopping cart component by making them `public shoppingCartItems$ Observable<ISticker[]> = of ([])` and then subscribing that `public shoppingCartItems: ISticker[] = [];`
 but when I place them into my html in an ngfor loop it tells me the properties are undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CartService} from '../cart.service'
  import {  of } from 'rxjs';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import { ISticker } from '../classes/isticker';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-cart-component',
  templateUrl: './shopping-cart-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-cart-component.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingCartComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  public shoppingCartItems$: Observable<ISticker[]> = of([]);
  public shoppingCartItems: ISticker[] = [];



  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { 
    this.shoppingCartItems$ = this
      .cartService
      .getItems();

    this.shoppingCartItems$.subscribe(_ => this.shoppingCartItems = _);  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

In my HTMl I've tried using the async pipe line to unwrap the information

```
<p>You have {{shoppingCartItems.length}} items in your bag</p>
<ng-container *ngIf=" shoppingCartItems$ | async as shoppingCartStickers"></ng-container>

<app-home *ngFor="let sticker of shoppingCartStickers">
     <p>{{sticker.description}}</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
</app-home>
```

the output to the page shows `<p>You have {{shoppingCartItems.length}} items in your bag</p>` the amount of items in the cart but doesn't show any of the properties attached to the variable in the loop nor does it show the other paragraph tag.

```
export class CartService {
  private itemsInCartSubject: BehaviorSubject<ISticker[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private itemsInCart: ISticker[] = [];


  constructor() {
    this.itemsInCartSubject.subscribe(_ => this.itemsInCart = _);
   }

   public addToCart(item: ISticker){
    this.itemsInCartSubject.next([...this.itemsInCart, item]);
   }


   public getItems(): Observable<ISticker[]> {
    return this.itemsInCartSubject.asObservable();
   }
```

This is my `cart.services.ts` for reference. This is my first time posting to stack overflow so if there is anything that would be helpful to see please let me know as I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to only show the relevant parts to debug this problem.

Comment: @RachidO I cleaned it up a little hope this helps and thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can have your `ShoppingCartComponentComponent` something like this:

```
export class ShoppingCartComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    public shoppingCartStickers: ISticker[] = [];

    constructor(
        private cartService: CartService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cartService.getItems()
            .subscribe(items => {
                this. shoppingCartStickers = items;
            });
    }
}
```

Now, `shoppingCartStickers` can be directly used in the component html:

```
<p>You have {{shoppingCartStickers?.length}} items in your bag</p>
<ng-container *ngIf="shoppingCartStickers?.length">
    <app-home *ngFor="let sticker of shoppingCartStickers">
        <p>{{sticker.description}}</p>
        <p>stuff</p>
    </app-home>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

> the output to the page shows You have {{shoppingCartItems.length}} items in your bag the amount of items in the cart

It's because you use `shoppingCartItems` which calculated in subscribe and will be up to date on every emitted event from `shoppingCartItems$`.

> but doesn't show any of the properties attached to the variable in the loop nor does it show the other paragraph tag

It's because the template variable `shoppingCartStickers` available only in the block you define it. So you just need to do:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(shoppingCartItems$ | async) as shoppingCartStickers">
  <app-home *ngFor="let sticker of shoppingCartStickers">
    <p>{{sticker.description}}</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
  </app-home>
</ng-container>
```

---

I recommended you to use single variable for that. You don't need to do `shoppingCartItems$ | async as shoppingCartStickers` in template because this data has already stored in the `shoppingCartItems` property of the component.

Comment: Hey @v.kostenko thank you for peeking at this. I've applied what you suggested but the property is still coming back as undefined. however the secondary `<p>stuff</p>` is now coming back with appropriate text. This must have fixed the loop.

Comment: I suppose I forget to add brackets around `shoppingCartItems$ | async`. Please see updated answer

Comment: This unfortunately did not work still. the property that are attached to the interface `ISticker` are still coming back as undefined. I maybe having a problem with my initial container as in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have misplaced the ending tag of `<ng-container>`.

What you have is essentially:

```html
<ng-container>
  <!-- Stickers available ONLY here -->
</ng-container>

<!-- Some code that tries to use stickers, but they are not available in this score --!>
```

The correct usage of `ng-contaner` is to actually wrap it AROUND the elements that require the data you're fetching from the service.

In any case, I would not use the `ng-container` here at all. You use case is:

1. You have an observable of an array: `Observable<ISticker[]>`
2. You want to create an element for each of the `ISticker` objects.

For this you can combine `async` pipe together with `*ngFor`:

```html
<app-home *ngFor="let sticker of shoppingCartItems$ | async">
    <p>{{sticker.description}}</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
</app-home>
```

---

Separately from this, you want to peek at the length of the array to display an extra `p` tag.

Since you already have the access to the observable, you can easily do

```html
<p>You have {{(shoppingCartItems$|async)?.length}} items in your bag</p>
<!-- OR -->
<p *ngIf="shoppingCartItems$|async as items">
  You have {{items.length}} items in your bag
</p>
```

The problem with this is that now you're accessing `shoppingCartItems$` TWICE: one time for the list of items, and one time to get the length. If you're getting this data from an API, this can easily result in TWO requests.

To combat this problem, you can use `shareReplay` operator, which will allow multiple subscribers to use the same value from a single observable:

```js
export class ShoppingCartComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  public shoppingCartItems$: Observable<ISticker[]>;

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.shoppingCartItems$ = this.cartService.getItems()
        .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zy6ptx) with this example, where you can see how this works.

Now you are free to use `shoppingCartItems$` any number of times, and this won't cause any unintended behaviour.

On top of that, now we don't manually subscribe, which means that the `async` pipe will get rid of the subscription for us when the component is destroyed, preventing a potential memory leak.

Comment: The `shareReplay` was something I was unaware of. I didn't state this in my post but I'm pretty new to programming and finding ways to do something once is very useful. Unfortunately with this solution the properties are still coming back as undefined. I'm thinking there is something wrong with my interface `ISticker` that isn't letting the the properties on. Thank you @hlfrmn!

Comment: @QuinnHernandez Are you getting any error? Are you sure that your `app-home` component supports `ng-content`? (Seeing how you add `p` tags inside your `<app-home>` tags). Maybe your `app-home` is expecting an input instead? (`<app-home [sticker]="sticker">`)

Comment: Ok so I changed the syntax to the way you have it here `<app-home [sticker] = "sticker">` and it populated all my items from my home component but now I'm unsure on how to get the specific info I need from the cart. I hope I'm making sense with this mate. Thank you again for the advice here @hlfrmn. EDIT - also the error that is coming back is  "cannot read property of undefined 'description'"

Comment: I used your example from stackblitz and you've again taught me more about constuctiing a component template but it is still reading the properties as undefined. I'm unsure where to go from here but I wanted to update a comment and say thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try to post your example on Stackblitz? Chances are you might find what your issue was just while writing the example.